# Where is ssl_module being loaded and why can't I bind to port 443?

Tags: apache-httpd

When I try to start httpd I get the following error:

```
# service httpd start || journalctl -xn
..
[so:warn] [pid 425] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd[425]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
httpd[425]: no listening sockets available, shutting
```

Syntax is OK:

```
# httpd -t
[so:warn] [pid 917] AH01574: module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax OK
```

Ok, fine. So `ssl_module.so` is being loaded twice. Except that it's not:

```
# grep -ir ssl_module /etc/httpd/*
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

It also says that something is listening on port 443. Except that there isn't:

```
# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      336/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      336/sshd
```

And I'm only listening once in my httpd configuration:

```
# grep -ir 443 /etc/httpd/*
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:Listen 443
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:<VirtualHost *:443>
```

There are no services being run by apache:

```
# top -u apache
..
(nothing)
```

This looks to be as if apache is loading some other conf somewhere which is loading ssl_module.so and listening on port 443 because of the warning and the error that the socket is already in use.

But the question is.. where is it??

This is from a VPS configuration running CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511.

Comment: Does `fuser 443/tcp` show anything?

Comment: It does not. There is nothing listening on port 443 until I attempt to start the httpd service.

Comment: Does `httpd -t` display `Syntax OK`?

Comment: Syntax is OK. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you check if `Listen 443` line on ports.conf exists?

Comment: There are no results for `# find /etc -name ports.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being a duplicate line in httpd.conf causing ssl.conf to be loaded twice.

There was a line:

`Include conf.d/*.conf`

And then further down:

`IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`

The first one was removed and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug is to run the server from a terminal session in debug mode `apache2 -X` or `httpd -X` depending on your build.  You can increase the verbosity with the `-e` flag.  The command `-S` flag will dump the configuration.  Additional flags are documented in the `man` page.

The `-M` flag will list loaded modules.  SSL is often provided as a module that needs to be loaded before you can enable HTTPS.

Comment: That PID is listening on port 22 and is my active SSH session. You can even see on the right that PID 336 belongs to sshd.

Comment: @Zhro Missed the port.   Try the debug options before you try to start the service.